# Хук  нажатия клавиш на java.

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Я пишу программу на java, которая должна сидеть в трее и при нажатии ctrl разворчиваться. Есть ли в java какие-нибудь библиотеки для того чтобы перехватить нажатие нажатие клавиш,  не имея фокуса на объектах формы и на самой форме? Короче для свёрнутого приложения.
Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Используете [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) для того, чтоб использовать WINAPI. В принципе сам по себе тот факт, что вы пытаетесь это сделать, настораживает.

Comment: Да, про jni я знаю, спасибо. Это я пытаюсь сделать для общего развития..

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, есть способ проще - программа не обязательно должна содержать ГУИ, потому достаточно в фоновом режиме, в отдельном потоке, оставить слушателя на нажатие ctrl.

Comment: Так всё равно нужен же будет фокус на объекте, чтобы он слушал..